"Evaluating a complex integral involving the Dirac delta function to calculate the surface area of a 2N-dimensional hypersphere"
I'm working on deriving the surface area of a 2N-dimensional hypersphere using the Dirac delta function and Fourier transform. I've reached the following integral:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\pi^{N-1}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[\pi \delta(k) + \frac{i}{k}\right]^N  e^{ik} dk
$$
where $\delta(k)$ is the Dirac delta function.
This integral arose from the following steps:

Starting with the integral representation of the hypersphere surface area using the Dirac delta function.
Applying the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta function.
Using polar coordinates and a change of variable to simplify the resulting multidimensional integral.

I'm unsure how to proceed with evaluating this final integral. Specifically:

How should I handle the $[\pi \delta(k) + i/k]^N$ term?
What techniques would be most appropriate for solving this integral?
Is there a way to show that this integral equals $2(\pi^N)/N!$, which is the known formula for the surface area of a $2N$-dimensional hypersphere?

Any insights, hints, or solution strategies would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

In general, powers of Dirac delta functions are not meaningful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751916/powers-of-the-dirac-delta-function
